# IIS restriction error for .aspx page, but .aspx is not restricted

Tags: windows, iis, web-config, targetprocess

I have recently tried to install TargetProcess http://www.targetprocess.com/ on my windows machine, which involves installing IIS and an instance of SQLEXPRESS.

I have no previous with IIS so most to the concepts where new to me. After much head scratching and tinkering I managed to get TargetProcess to install. However when I try to run it in a browser I get teh following error

> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the Web server.

The page I am trying to run is .aspx and I have run a page.aspx to verify that .aspx are not being restricted as suggested by the error message.

Anyone got any ideas as to what else it could be?

Comment: do you have .Net framework installed and IIS configured to use ASP.Net for the site?

Comment: .Net Framework is installed. How do I check if it is configured in IIS?

Comment: Kevin, please contact our live chat support - they will help for sure http://messenger.providesupport.com/messenger/targetprocess.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kevin,

In the IIS management console, please open ISAPI and CGI Restrictions feature fro your hosting server. ASP.NET v2.0 and v4.0 restrictions are set separately. TargetProcess application is using .NET v4.0 since 2.22.9 build, so please check, that MS .NET framework v4.0 is installed and ASP.NET v4.0 is allowed. Also on the Handler Mappings section for TP web site PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0 should be enabled.

Please contact us via http://messenger.providesupport.com/messenger/targetprocess.html if you need any assistance.

Regards, Alex - TargetPro

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

1.- Go to IIS manager and clic on your server name (when tooltip says localhosts)

2.- double clic on ASAPI and CGI restriction

3.- right clic to change all items to ALLOWED

Answer (score 1):

The "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" option was not there on my machine.  I had to go back into the "Turn windows features on and off", then the "Internet Information Services" / "World Wide Web Services" / "Application Development Features" and then ticked the "CGI" option.  Once I did this, the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" option appeared after I closed and re-opened IIS.  Just mentioning it here in case anyone else has the same problem.